# Any workaround to import leads in a Group edition?

Tags: leads, import, group-edition

WE have a Group edition and we wanted to import leads from a csv file. But when i tried using apex data loader i couldnt login as it API access is not enabled for Group editions.

Does anyone know of any workaround to get the leads into SF.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/importing.htm

Was looking at this documentation.Felt still you will have import wizard there to help you.

Lead import not available in: Personal and Contact Manager Editions

So its available in Group for sure .can you try using that

Comment: Thanks Mohit.. I ended up using the import tool under leads tab. Thanks for the pointer